# How to configure vhosts/apache subdomains for dev environment?

Tags: php, apache, docker, dockerfile, vhosts

I have difficulties configuring access to sub domains for PHP project. Works only localhost. 
vhosts (localhost.conf, backoffice.website.conf, etc) are copied to Docker machine from docker-compose line: `./dev/conf/default/sites/:/etc/apache2/from-host` and appended to apache2.conf in Dockerfile. What is wrong ?

Subdomains:

```
localhost => public_html/www/index.php (this works)
backoffice.website => public_html/backoffice/index.php
api.website => public_html/api/index.php
health.website => public_html/health/index.php
```

working **localhost.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@website.ee
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/public_html/www
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAlias localhost

        <Directory /var/www/dev/public_html/www>
                        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/website.error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/website.access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|svg|map)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

other vhosts doesn't seem to be working e.g **backoffice.website.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost backoffice.website:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@website.ee
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/public_html/backoffice
        ServerName backoffice.website


        <Directory /var/www/dev/public_html/backoffice>
                        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I could not get working access to website if I change localhost to "website" in vhost.
Maybe I did not enable

My **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN pecl install redis-5.1.1 \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis xdebug \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && mkdir /var/www/dev \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www

RUN mkdir -p  /etc/apache2/from-host

RUN echo "" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && echo "# Include the configurations from the host machine" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && echo "IncludeOptional from-host/*.conf" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite \
    && service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www/dev
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./dev:/var/www/dev/
      - ./dev/conf/default/sites/:/etc/apache2/from-host
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=10.10.10.219
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `*:80` in the VirtualHost directives and just vary the ServerName and ServerAliases to match the alternate hostnames in your requests.

For debugging, see `apachectl -S`

Comment: can't access from host machine via custom domain ("website") even to main vhost. Added 0.0.0.0 website to /etc/hosts on host machine. still only accessible through localhost:8080